# Error al obtener datos de mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

estoy intentando obtener los usuarios de una base en mongodb, cuando intento relizar el find a un modulo exportado de la base de datos, me dice is not a function

```
const db = require ('../../../../config/db')
const getUsers =  (req,res)=>{
db.find()
.then(function (users){
  console.log(users)  
  console.log(err)
});
```

El modulo que exporto es el siguiente

```
module.exports = async()=>
{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(URL, {
            maxPoolSize: 50,
            wtimeoutMS: 2500,
            useNewUrlParser: true
        })
        console.log('DB connected ')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el modulo que se exporta es el que llamas `db`, entonces es una funcion que no esta retornando nada